# Best way to treat (too) many classes in one categorical variable

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, preprocessor

I'm working on a ML prediction model and I have a dataset with a categorical variable (let's say product id) and I have 2k distinct products.

If I convert this variable with dummy variables like one hot enconder, the dataset may have a size of 2k times the number of examples (millions of examples), but it's too many to be processed.

1. How is this used to be treated?
2. Should I use the variable only with the whitout the conversion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High cardinality of categorial features is a well-known problem and "the best" way typically depends on the prediction task and requires a trial-and-error approach. It is case-dependent if you can even find a strategy that is clearly better than others.

Addressing your first question, a good collection of different encoding strategies is provided by the [`category_encoders`](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/) library:

> A set of scikit-learn-style transformers for encoding categorical variables into numeric

They follow the `scikit-learn` API for transformers and a simple example is provided as well. Again, which one will provide the best results depends on your dataset and the prediction task. I suggest incorporating them in a pipeline and test (some or all of) them.

In regard to your second question, you would then continue to use the encoded features for your predictions and analysis.